# Rails view breaks however the console doesn't

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, associations

I am following a tutorial about rails and I'm facing a weird (the way I see it) thing.

I have a database that contains 1 post and 3 comments. The comments and posts are separated in different tables however the comments has a foreign key attribute that points to the posts table. The first post has 2 comments associated with it and the rails console shows these.

```
p = Post.all
first = p[0]
comments = first.comments // Returns all the comments that have the post_id equal with the first post
```

The problems comes when I try to see these in my view. I navigate to the `localhost:3000/posts/3/comments/` and I see all of the comments however I only want to see the comments associated to that post. ( in my case the post with the id of 3)

Here is my `routes.rb`

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :comments

  resources :posts do
      resources :comments
  end
end
```

**Note**
The console behaves fine when I call the `comments` method returning the right comments ( only those associated with the post however the view shows all of the comments not only those associated

Here are the models:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy
end

class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :post
end
```

Here is `comments/index.html.erb`:

```
<h1>Listing comments</h1>

<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Post</th>
      <th>Body</th>
      <th colspan="3"></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <% @comments.each do |comment| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= comment.post_id %></td>
        <td><%= comment.body %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Show', comment %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_comment_path(comment) %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', comment, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>

<br>

<%= link_to 'New Comment', new_comment_path %>
```

Here is the `comments_controller`:

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_comment, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /comments
  # GET /comments.json
  def index
    @comments = Comment.all
  end
end
```

Comment: Could you please post the relevant code in your view as well as the corresponding controller action?

Comment: @mmichael I have included the models. The views and controllers have been generated through the `rails generate scaffold ...`  and I have not touched them

Comment: If the problem lies in your view then we'll need to see the code in the view in order to help you. Although I have a feeling the issue will be in your controller action (for the said view) so please post that as well.

Comment: @mmichael I have tried to add only the necessary code. Do you need anything else?

Comment: I edited your post to remove the unnecessary `posts` controller and view. @Mandeep's answer will do the trick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> and I see all of the comments however I only want to see the comments associated to that post

In your index action you would have something like

```
@comments = Comment.all # this will have all the comments
```

which is rendering all of your comments in view so you need to change it to this:

```
def index
  @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
  @comments = @post.comments #this will have comments associated with @post
end
```

**Update:**

You can't have two same resources like this. You need to use [**`shallow nesting`**](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#shallow-nesting) in your routes so your routes will look like this:

```
resources :posts do
  resources :comments, only: [:index, :new, :create]
end
resources :comments, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
```

Comment: This breaks `localhost:3000/comments/`

Comment: @Bula did you want the `/comments` route? Based on the association between Posts and Comments, you'd want to keep the original nesting in your routes. If you want the `/comments` route that displays ALL the comments then you can simply add a route specifically for that.

Comment: @mmichael yeah but in question bula specified `I see all of the comments however I only want to see the comments associated to that post` so i don't think he wants to show all the comments

Comment: I think the tutorial confused me a bit. I looked at it again and there are no other comments other than those associated to the related post in the database ( this means that I wasn't able to see that the code broke there. I thought it was me having a problem). So probably in future tutorials it will go in more depth. Thanks for this answer as it solves the question